# How to increase the size of the buttons on a tool strip?

Tags: winforms, c#-3.0

I have added a tool strip to my form. In this tool strip i had some buttons with the help of add toolstrip button. These buttons are by default of the size 22, 20. But i want to change the size of the button to 25, 50. I made changes in designer by changing the size property but it is not reflected in my form. Even if i change the height of the tool strip, it is not getting changed. Any help with that?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

If you change `AutoSize` property of ToolStripButton to `false`, you'll be able to change the width of button.

If you change `AutoSize` property of ToolStrip to `false`, you'll be able to change its height and the ToolStripButton will change its height automatically to fit into the tool strip.

**EDIT:** 
If you want to increase not only size of the button, but also the size of the button image, you must either use the bigger image, or you can try to resize the original one. Then you must also change toolstrip's `ImageScalingSize` property. Try to use the following code:

```
//change the dimensions of button itself
toolStrip1.AutoSize = false; toolStrip1.Height = 50;
toolStripButton1.AutoSize = false; toolStripButton1.Width = 50;

//resize the image of the button to the new size
int sourceWidth = toolStripButton1.Image.Width;
int sourceHeight = toolStripButton1.Image.Height;
Bitmap b = new Bitmap(40, 40);
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage((Image)b))
{
   g.InterpolationMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.InterpolationMode.HighQualityBicubic;
   g.DrawImage(toolStripButton1.Image, 0, 0, 40, 40);
}
Image myResizedImg = (Image)b;

//put the resized image back to the button and change toolstrip's ImageScalingSize property 
toolStripButton1.Image = myResizedImg;
toolStrip1.ImageScalingSize = new Size(40, 40);
```

Comment: Well, it changes the size of the toolstripbutton, as you wanted... So I guess what you really want to do is to resize also the image button... I've edited my answer...

Comment: Thanks! It worked. Is it possible to have two tool strips one over another in one form at the right end of the form?

Comment: I undocked the toolstrip but now the buttons on  the tool strip have disappeared. They appear only when i click on the small arrow at the bottom. Any idea please?

Comment: Nice to know image scale size  property

Answer (score 28):

just

```
toolStrip1.ImageScalingSize = new Size(40, 40);
```

That's all ;)

Answer (score 4):

The simplest solution:

Just change the ImageScalingSize property of the Tool Strip on the Property Toolbar.

That's it :)